# Store in MySQL and display variable amount of rows in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'll try to explain the problem as best as I can, I'll put numbers on the problem to showcase it better but this might not be real:

I have a little system where up to 2 teachers grade a student performing a task. The student will have to perform say 10 tasks, so in total the student is graded by up to 20 teachers.

Each task shares some of the same questions but not all of them, say in Task1 teachers are presented with 10 grading points for example "1. Emphaty to patient:" then 5 radio buttons with which they grade the student. (A lowest, E highest).

But then in Task2 there might not be a patient so that can't be graded. So we skip question 1 and maybe 2 and start at 3. So those questions are not displayed to the teacher. So we end up with a variable amount of gradings per task, some might have 5 some 10, etc.

I have a table with the student info, another with the teachers info, task info (which includes questions to be asked in said task) and finally one with the evaluations:

```
+------------+------------+---------+---------------+-----+
| id_student | id_teacher | id_task | grades        | ... |
+------------+------------+---------+---------------+-----+
| 1          | 2          | 4       | E,C,D,B,C,D,E |     |
| 1          | 25         | 5       | A,E,B,C       |     |
| 1          | 8          | 6       | E,D,C,C,D,D   |     |
+------------+------------+---------+---------------+-----+
```

At first I thougt storing the grades separated by a comma would be ok, and then use php explode to retrieve it, it works for storing and displaying info per user per task and else but, first I don't know if this is good practice, second I'm now at the point of displaying the results for all students into a HTML table, but then how do I get the max amount of grades to decide the amount of the table fields and then how do I tell which grades goes where so I get:

```
+---------+---------+------+---------+------------+---------+-----+
| Student | Teacher | Task | Grade 1 | Grade 2    | Grade 3 | ... |
+---------+---------+------+---------+------------+---------+-----+
| 1       | 2       | 4    | E       | C          | D       | ... |
| 1       | 25      | 5    | NULL    | NULL       | A       | ... |
| 1       | 8       | 6    | E       | D          | NULL    | ... |
+---------+---------+------+---------+------------+---------+-----+
```

So finally the question is, is there a better way to aproach this? as in another table to store grades but then how to tell the amount of columns and finally how would be a better way to display it in HTML?

Comment: Yes. See normalisation.

Comment: Hi, thanks I'll look into it. I just thought of smething but not sure; What if I make a grading table where I have the evaluation id and one record per answer, so say 10 records for id_evaluation 1, etc. Although i'm still unsure about the HTML part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normalised environment *might* look as follows. Note that there is a degree of redundancy here. That redundancy can be addressed by splitting the data out into separate tables as appropriate.

```
+---------+---------+------+----------+-------+
| Student | Teacher | Task | Grade_no | Grade |
+---------+---------+------+----------+-------+
|       1 |      2  |   4  |       1  | E     |
|       1 |      2  |   4  |       2  | C     |
|       1 |      2  |   4  |       3  | D     |
|       1 |     25  |   5  |       3  | A     |
|       1 |      8  |   6  |       1  | E     |
|       1 |      8  |   6  |       2  | D     |
+---------+---------+------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, I was thinking maybe in table evaluations I have: id_evaluation, id_student, id_teacher, id_task and then get rid of the grades column. Make another table Grades and have id_grades, id_evaluation, grade_no as you said and finally Grade. With id_evaluation I can get the id_student and teacher so I only have it once

Comment: Yes. That seems sensible.

Comment: From this Grade table then I could query max(Grade_no) so I would get the highest amount of possible questions among all the tasks so I get all my HTML columns? Right? I'll try it but I think you just answered my question, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think so. You'd normally just gather the results into an ordered array, and then use a php loop to spit the results into either a) a pretty table or b) (and more common these days) a bit of json. I'd show you how, but I'm really no php coder.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll look into that as well, but the Database part was more worrisome. Your answer will also make the code easier to understand. Thank you.